Как добавить parse_mode при отправке через send_media_group?
У меня есть бот, который получает сообщение, обрабатывает текст сообщения и отправляет его потом обратно пользователю с той же самой медией. Но сейчас у меня проблема, если отправлять через send_media_group то я не знаю как сделать parse_mode='html'.
Код для понимания:
def send_media_group_with_buttons(chat_id, media_group, caption, message_id):
    media = [types.InputMediaPhoto(item['media'], caption=caption if i == 0 else '') for i, item in enumerate(media_group) if item['type'] == 'photo']
    media += [types.InputMediaVideo(item['media'], caption=caption if i == 0 else '') for i, item in enumerate(media_group) if item['type'] == 'video']

    try:
        bot.send_media_group(chat_id, media)
        send_media_group_buttons(chat_id, "Выберите действие для группы сообщений:", message_id)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ошибка при отправке медиа группы: {e}")

Сначало я попробывал изменить кое что:
media = [types.InputMediaPhoto(item['media'], caption=caption, parse_mode='html' if i == 0 else '') for i, item in enumerate(media_group) if item['type'] == 'photo']

media += [types.InputMediaVideo(item['media'], caption=caption, parse_mode='html' if i == 0 else '') for i, item in enumerate(media_group) if item['type'] == 'video']

Но тогда caption вообще не передается и приходит медиа группа без текста. Пытался найти какую то инфу в инете, но безуспешно...
Любые вопросы в коментах
